# SUM IF when a text string meets a specific numeric value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Okay it might sound weird but I need to calculate points for each employee where:
LT(Tardy) = 0.50 pts
A(Absent) = 1 pt

The table looks like this:

```
12/1/22   12/2/22   12/3/22   12/4/22       Total Points
  A         LT       LT        LT                ?
```

[image]

Can I calculate total points in a range where LT is 0.50 pts and A =  1 pt??

Thanks!!

I can not figure out SUMIF to calculate total where a text string meets a specific numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:D2,"A")+COUNTIFS(A2:D2,"LT")/2
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, you can also use arrays of criteria and values like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:D2,{"A","LT"})*{1,0.5})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, I am late, as the solutions posted by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, & **[Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory)** Sir are very **useful**, however sharing one more alternative way.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=SUM((A2:D2={"A";"LT"})*{1;0.5})
```

---

Let me show you what it creates, before wrapping within `SUM()`

[image]

---

It creates an array of 2 rows x 4 columns, next we are multiplying by {1;0.5} matrix calculation,

[image]

---

Last but not least to get the counts we are summing the matrix which returns 2.5.

Answer (score -1):

A short one for this specific case (two possible values):

```
=SUM(IF(A2:D2="A",1,0.5))
```

[image]